# AttributeError: type object 'IP' has no attribute 'SubnetSet'

Tags: server, python, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to install OpenVPN access server on a virtual server with Ubuntu 14.04 OS. But I get this error:

```
Use local authentication via internal DB?
> Press ENTER for default [no]: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/openvpn_as/bin/_ovpn-init", line 474, in <module>
    priv_nets = NetInfoLinux.get_priv_subnets()
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pyovpn/net/net.py", line 403, in get_priv_subnets
AttributeError: type object 'IP' has no attribute 'SubnetSet'
```

Anybody know how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're installing the openvpn-as i386 package when what you need is the x86_x64 package. I ran into this earlier today.